# Intense Javascript Freezes Browser

Tags: javascript

So I have a sections of code that is going to be running at least 10 seconds (It is going through around 14000000(14 states* 1000000 for numTimes) iterations of doing stuff. I need to make sure the browser doesn't stop responding part way through as it currently is. I looked at the question [How to stop intense Javascript loop from freezing the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714942/how-to-stop-intense-javascript-loop-from-freezing-the-browser)

However, I can't use a setTimeout because of the function needing a reference to this. I did try to make a temporary variable that stores this and pass that to a setTimeout, but it wouldn't recognize my functions and variables of the new variable = this. (This is an object that stores tables, arrays, an array of objects, and some data) Any ideas?

```
Agent.prototype.performActions = function(numTimes)
{
    /* perform a random action for every state
        numTimes.
    */
    var len = this.states.length; // get the amount of states
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) // loop over every state
    {
        var state = this.states[i]; // the current state so we don't lose time accessing it again
        if(state.terminal != 1) // not a terminal state
        {
            for(var j=0; j < numTimes; j++) // the num of times to do a random action perstate
            {
                var that = this;
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var acts = state.actions.length; // the number of actions
                    var randAct = Math.floor((Math.random() * acts)); // random actions between 0 and 3
                    var randProb = Math.random(); // number between 0 and 1 to figure out which state we end up in
                    var locs = that.states[i].locations[randAct]; // saves time
                    var tote=0;
                    var alen = that.states[i].actions[randAct].length
                    for(var k=0; k < alen; k++) //num of state checking
                    {
                        tote += that.states[i].actions[randAct][k];
                        if(randProb <= tote)
                        {
                            // we found where we landed
                            that.states[i].actCounts[randAct] += 1;
                            var numPos = locs.length;

                            for(var l=0; l < numPos; l++) // get the num of possible states
                            {
                                if(locs[l].stateNum == k)
                                {
                                    count += 1;
                                    that.states[i].locations[randAct][l].times += 1;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    var inner = document.getElementById("run").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("run").innerHTML = inner+"<p>Finished with performActions num actions = " + count + "</p>";
}                       for(var l=0; l < numPos; l++) // get the num of possible states
                        {
                            if(locs[l].stateNum == k)
                            {
                                count += 1;
                                that.states[i].locations[randAct][l].times += 1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }, 1);
        }
    }
}
var inner = document.getElementById("run").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("run").innerHTML = inner+"<p>Finished with performActions num actions = " + count + "</p>";
```

}

Comment: You can certainly pass `this` to a `setTimeout` function in every circumstance I can think of.

Comment: You need a different name for the variable that you assign `this` to. Commonly, people use `that`.

Comment: I tried using that.....

Comment: Then why wouldn't it work

Comment: everywhere I reference this.anything that I change to that. was undefined.

Comment: Doing the setTimeout with passing that actually made this freeze the browser way more than before. I only had to continue script twice before. This is already my tenth time continuing script and it is still going.

Comment: @DragonTorchSlash [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).. what you can do is call async.each on `state` array.. and process all 14 states in parallel.. you can further do async.each on action array.. but thats upto you.. I mean what works.. well for you... FYI it'll significantly increase your memory..