# HighCharts showLoading() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, highcharts, loading

I have a chart and a button which calls a very heavy processing, as in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/v97e5vs1/1/

```
$button.click(function () {
        chart.showLoading();
        for (var i=0;i<20;i++) {
                var d=[];
            for (var j=0;j<12;j++) {
                d.push(Math.random()*200)            
                        }
        chart.addSeries({data:d});    
        }
        chart.hideLoading();
});
```

However, the `showLoading` function doesn't work as expected: the broser window hang up until the processing is finished.

What's wrong?

Comment: showLoading() just changes the display of the chart - it does not do anything more - if your loop freezes the browser then you need to move the loop to a webworker process or use some async technique like the one in the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714942/how-to-stop-intense-javascript-loop-from-freezing-the-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve performance you can ask highcharts not to redraw when you add the series by setting the [`redraw`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Chart.addSeries) parameter to `false`. Once adding is complete [`redraw`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Chart.redraw) can be called.

Not the prettiest solution but you can draw the chart within a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to allow it enough time to display the loading message.

Example:

```js
// the button handler
var isLoading = false,
  $button = $('#button'),
  chart;

chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});



$button.click(function() {
  chart.showLoading();

  setTimeout(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      var d = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        d.push(Math.random() * 250)
      }
      chart.addSeries({
        data: d
      }, false);
    }

    chart.redraw();
    chart.hideLoading();
  }, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<button id="button">Show loading</button>
```

Comment: The "heavy processing" function of my code was only an example. I don't use `addSeries` function. Anyway, I thank you for your reply citing also `setTimeout` that I was thinking about, too.

Comment: Depending on what the _heavy processing_ involves you could make use of the [Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Worker)